# $\lim \arcsin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)/f(x)$ for $f(x)$ that goes to $0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

this might be a trivial question for some of you but I'm really not sure about it.
(I can't use latex sorry)

For $f(x)\to >0$, $\lim \arcsin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)/f(x) = 1$? And mostly, why/why not?

Thank you all very much, have a nice day :)

Comment: Just take care that $f(x) \neq 0$ when $f(x) \to 0$ and then your result holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, with *equivalence*: near $0$, we have $\arcsin u\sim u$ which means exactly that $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\arcsin u}u=1,$$
therefore, by substitution,
$$\lim_{f(x)\to 0}\frac{\arcsin\bigl(f(x)\bigr)}{f(x)}=1.$$

Comment: Thank you, i know that rule for the sine but i wasn't sure if it applied to the inverse too.

Comment: The equivalence is obtained as the first non-zero term in  Taylor's expansion of $\arcsin$ near $0$.